# Duration format in google spreadsheet

Tags: format, google-sheets, duration

I'm trying to apply a duration format to some cells in google spreadsheet. I would like to convert an integer number in a format: X days x hours x minutes.

I've tried with some formats like: d:h:mm but i found a problem when I apply the format. It always put one day less. When I write 1 in the cell the convert to 31:0:00. When I write 2 the cells changes to 1:00:00.

Comment: so if you have DAYS, HOURS and MINUTES how are you storing them / where are you getting them from? as a value is one cell? as value in multiple cells? as a calculation? ALSO **what is "1" supposed to mean?** - 1 day? If so how would you write "1 day and and 6 hours"?

Comment: I have the duation in days unit. For example 1 day and 12 hours will be 1,5. I would like to apply a custom format to the cell where the number is written and see it like: 1day 12 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the duration format is actually a date / time format (for comparing dates).
If you simply enter a number (1) google will interpret that as `midnight` (as times are stored as fractions of whole days) `of the reference day number 1`.
Reference day in Google Sheets is **31/12/1899** - IE the 31st day of the month. That is why your result returns days=31.

To achieve what you want you effectively want to add 1 to your values. so that 1 (+1) actually becomes "2 days since 31/12/1899 - ie 01/01/1900 - ie 1 day, and you could then use custom format for display, but this wont work when you have >31 days.

---

I think the best way is to simply concatenate the data you have with relavent parts like so (where A1 is a cell containg your data - 1,2,1.5 etc):

```
=int(A1)&" days "&int(MOD(A1,1)*24)&" hours " & mod(MOD(A1,1)*24,1)*60 & " minutes"
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding 1 is a possible solution but it is not completely clear when opperates with the cells. For example, if I sum 4 cells that contains a number 2 (= 1 day), the results will be 7 days (4cells*2days -1 (bacause of your explanation)) and not 4 days like I want.